# Is killing of a scorpion or snake not himsa according to the scriptures?

Tags: dharma, animals

In Srimad-Bhagavatam (7.9.14), we get

> modeta sādhur api vṛścika-sarpa-hatyā
>
> (..**Even saintly persons take pleasure in the killing of a scorpion or a snake..**)

Gita on the other hand clearly says that

> 12.13 **He who is not hateful towards any creature, who is friendly and compassionate,** who has no idea of 'mine' and the idea of egoism, who is the same under sorrow and happiness, **who is forgiving**;
>
> **is a true Devotee.**

The above two seem contradictory to me.How can a forgiving and compassionate saintly person take pleasure in the killing of a scorpion or a snake?

Is there any way of reconciling the above two statements found in our holy scripture?

**UPDATE**

I got the translation in an answer to one of my questions, Its an ISKCON translation : https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/7/9/14

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it is 'himsa'. But I think first we have to see the context.This is being said by Prahlad who is trying to assuage the temper of angry Nrisimhadev just after He killed HiraNyaksaipu.

**SAdhu here does not mean a saintly person**. It means just 'a good person'. Nothing to do with spirituality here.

Also, 'modeta' is the third person singular present optative class 1 ātmanepada √mud, meaning 'should be pleased'. So '**modeta' does not mean 'takes pleasure'.**

**So the correct translation should be : Even a good person should be pleased by killing a scorpion or a snake.[ So kindly cool down.]**

**As it has nothing to do with a saintly person, the sloka of Gita is not applicable here and so there is no contradiction.**

So the basic problem is with the translation that is connoting something entirely different.

Reference: sanskritdictionary.com